# Java asynchronous return of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, consumer

If we have `AsyncResponse response` variable we can write something like:
`CompletableFuture#thenAccept(response::resume)`.
I don't understand how can we pass `boolean resume(Object response)` method from `AsyncResponse` class to `thenAccept()` which takes `Consumer` as parameter, because `Consumer` return `void`.

Comment: Can you try using thenApply(...)?

Comment: "How can we pass..." - by ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method reference will just ignore the return value. If you expand the method reference into an anonymous inner class, it would look like this:

```
completableFuture.thenAccept(new Consumer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Object object) {
            response.resume(object);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `completableFuture.thenAccept(response::resume);` would be enough.